# Where to put local settings for Android gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am not sure where to properly put local properties for a project (a file path in this case) for an Android Studio project built with gradle:

- local.properties: That would be what I need, however it is autogenerated and just used for the SDK-location
- gradle.properties (Project level): This file is checked into version control for us to guarantee the same JVM settings for all project members for example
- gradle.properties (Global): This would be possible, however I don't feel it is the correct place to put project specific settings

So either I overlooked a possibility or I must go the way of ignoring the project level gradle.properties

Comment: YOU MEAN `local.properties` file ?

Comment: As I said the local.properties file is auto-generated and might be overridden by Android Studio, so this is not a solution

Comment: You can keep your local property in this location `C:\Users\UserName\.Android`

Comment: Could you give an example for a **local** but still **project-specific** setting?

Comment: The example here is a file path from folders created by Qt that need to be imported into the project

Answer (score 0):

- `local.properties`: You can put informations about the SDK location but also, your sensitive data like username and password of your repo access and the location of your Key to sign the Apks.
- `gradle.properties` (Project level): It's only specified for the current project (or module) it contains dependencies, plugins, tasks, repositories for that project.
- `gradle.properties` (Global): Can contains same data as gradle.properties (Project level) except adding dependencies. Configuration in this file are taken for all subProjects (modules in that project). this file can be located also in your gradle home directory (userDir/.gradle). If you are working with a Proxy, the best place to configure your proxy is that file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put something specific in the local.properties then just over write once its being generated depending on the OS you have. It generates the SDK location by default but you can override like this from command line:

```
echo 'sdk.dir=/home/jenkins/Android/Sdk'  > ./local.properties
```

Then you can run your gradle to build the project.